# java: get count of values within a given key range of Guava Multimap

Tags: java, dictionary, guava, multimap, sortedmap

I have a `TreeMultimap<Integer, String>`, which includes duplicate keys also.

> I want to get the **count of values** which lies within a specific key
>   range, that too with **O(logN)** time complexity.

I tried by first converting the `TreeMultimap` to a `SortedMap` by using its method `asMap()` and then creating a `submap` in the required range and fetching its size.

```
SortedMap<Integer, Collection<String>> sortedMap = mapList.getTmm().asMap();
return sortedMap.subMap(beg,end).size();
```

Is it having complexity *O(logN)*?

Also, I faced a problem here. When a `TreeMultimap` is converted to `SortedMap`, the values are objects of `Collection` class. i.e. The key-value pair having duplicate keys in `TreeMultimap` is included in a single `Collection` class.
So the method `size()` returns wrong value.

Is there any other way I an achieve this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Is it having complexity O(logN)?" Doesn't matter, since it's not returning the right answer: it's not the count of the values, but rather the count of the keys.

Comment: Yes. Is there any other way? @AndyTurner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`SortedMultiset`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html), which has a method for ranged query:

**[`subMultiset`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html#line.136):**

> Returns a view of this multiset restricted to the range between lowerBound and upperBound.

**Sample code:**

```
import com.google.common.collect.*;

public class GuavaMultiMap {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Multimap<Integer, String> map = TreeMultimap.create();
        map.put(0, "-1");
        map.put(1, "a");
        map.put(1, "b");
        map.put(2, "c");
        map.put(2, "d");
        map.put(3, "e");

        SortedMultiset<Integer> keys = TreeMultiset.create();
        keys.addAll(map.keys());

        SortedMultiset<Integer> range = keys.subMultiset(1, BoundType.CLOSED, 3, BoundType.OPEN);
        System.out.println(range.size());
    }
}
```

**Output:** `4`

The above code does not operate in `O(log(N))` time because this line `keys.addAll(...);` is `O(n)`. However, if you keep a `SortedMultiset` updated together with the `Multimap`, you should be able to trade space for time.